# How to replace specific indexes in string?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I'm trying to pass dynamically hours and minutes to the `time_now` variable.

I want to pass time dynamically to `time_now`. I'm trying but unable to pass it.

Comment: It is hard to figure out what you mean by `date_time = 2022-02-10 14:18:58.209240+05:45`. That's  not valid Python. Show us what your code really says.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks for you reply. I've updated with an example. please check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strptime` to convert your string as a datetime then `replace` to change hour and minute:

```
from datetime import datetime

# split your time to be usable with replace
new_time = '16:50'
hour, minute = new_time.split(':')

# it's not mandatory if date_time is already a datetime instance
date_time = '2022-02-10 14:18:58.209240+05:45'
date_time = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

# replace each component with keyword args
new_time = date_time.replace(hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute))
```

Output:

```
>>> str(new_time)
'2022-02-10 16:50:58.209240+05:45'
```

Comment: @sruthi. I posted my answer before your update. Can you check if this solves your problem, please?

Comment: @ Corralien thanks for you answer. I'm checking with it. I'll update you on this. thanks once again